# How do I use the jQuery script for multiple divisions?

Tags: jquery, fade

I want the first pic to fade to the next pic on `mouseenter` and reverse on `mouseleave`.
I want to use the jQuery script for multiple id's

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#picone1').mouseenter(function(){
   $('#picone1').fadeToggle(500);
   $('#pictwo1').fadeToggle(500);
});
$('#pictwo1').mouseleave(function(){
   $('#picone1').fadeToggle(500);
   $('#pictwo1').fadeToggle(500);
});
</script>
<div id="fade">
   <img src="two.gif" width="100" height="100" id="pictwo1" style="display:none;"/>
   <img src="one.gif" width="100" height="100" id="picone1"/>
</div>
<div id="fade">
   <img src="two.gif" width="100" height="100" id="pictwo2" style="display:none;top: 300px;" />
   <img src="one.gif" width="100" height="100" id="picone2" style="top: 300px;" />
</div>
```

if I use

```
$('#picone1,#picone2').mouseenter(function(){
```

how to fade only the `div` over which the mouse has entered?

Is there any other or better script to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery inside of any event callback `this` refers to the DOM element that triggered the event. So if you do:

```
 $('#picone1, #picone2').mouseenter(function() {
     // $(this) refers to whichever div was entered, so you can do:
     $(this).fadeToggle(500);
     $(this).prev('img').fadeToggle(500); // get previous IMG in the DOM and fade
 });
```

I would recommend if you are just doing this a lot to give the images classes instead of IDs, so you can just do something like `$('img.before')` and refer to the other img relatively.

Comment: I tried the prev() function but after the first transition it goes blank for the second one. I updated the code on the above link based on prev() function. could you please post the code for the class method you told?